# React Native - Cut-off texts

Tags: react-native

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see on the attached image, some texts are getting cut-off. Those marked with red-colored question mark, there's supposed to be a letter or a word, but someshow its missing. So far this issue happens in some LG in Oppo phone models, haven't seen this issue in Samsung and iPhones.

I'm using a react native boiler plate called "ignite".

Thanks in advance and more power

PS: the screenshot is taken from an LG phone, this means that it happens in production also, i can't reproduce this on development using genymotion because i can't find an LG or Oppo emulator.

Comment: the "Moment" is supposed to be "Moments"

Comment: Check encoding of the files that hold text with a problem. IDK if that is a problem, is just something I would check to rule out.

Comment: ok tnx ill check the encoding

Answer (score 0):

In my experiences, this has been caused by a setting that exists on the phone that has a system-wide specific font that doesn't correlate with the default font of your app.

In order to mitigate this issue, let's say for instance your default app font is 'Lucida Grand' yet your system-wide font set in the settings of your phone is 'Roboto', you can ship your app with a TTF file of 'Lucida Grand' and set the default font of your app to 'Lucida Grand' so it avoids defaulting to the system-wide font on the phone.

See [this issue reported](https://forums.expo.io/clicks/track?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacebook%2Freact-native%2Fissues%2F15114&post_id=12189&topic_id=4999) that shows a similar situation.

Comment: tnx ill check that